# Combine text and use that as a variable in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to combine two strings "globalVariables.EditButton_" & Value of 'i' and pass that string e.g "globalVariables.EditButton_1" as a variable that should refer to the button element that we stored as a global variable. Below is my code, but it does not work.  The error is

> "Message:
>       Failed: Button.isDisplayed is not a function   Stack:
>       TypeError: Button.isDisplayed is not a function "

Code snippet:

```
it('should show the same data in both Page' , function(){

   var RowCount=  
globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).count() -1;

   for (var i=1; i < RowCount; ++i){
     var Button = 'globalVariables.Edit_Button_'+i;

     expect(Button.isDisplayed());


// do something

 }

});
```

How can I add two strings and use it as a variable in this case?

Comment: Should be `var Button = globalVariables['Edit_Button_'+i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet above, your `globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).count()` returns a [promise](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count). So when you are adding these together you are adding a promise to an int and an int. Next thing that looks odd: `var Button = 'globalVariables.Edit_Button_'+i;` This does not get evaluated as an elementFinder. I agree with yong's comment above where you should use `globalVariables['Edit_Button_'+i];`

### Using async / await

So I'm going to answer this question with async / await and the contorl flow turned off. This is with `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,` set in your configuration file.

```
it('should show the same data in both Page' , async () => {

  const RowCount=  
(await globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).count()) - 1;

  for (var i=1; i < RowCount; ++i){
    const button = globalVariables['Edit_Button_'+i];
    expect(await button.isDisplayed());

    // do something

  }
});
```